# Physical iOS device not connecting to Metro

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

Whenever I am running on a simulator, the app is working fine, but trying to run the app on a physical device isn't working. I have made sure both the device are on the same network and added the bundle url by shaking the app, but still no progress. I tried accessing the bundle url through Safari, with the 8081 port, but it says Safari couldn't connect to the server. Tried cleaning the cache with yarn, and redid pod installs, the app is allowed to connect via the local network but nothing works. Occasionally it shows the `No bundle URL present` error but that's about it.
xCode Version - 14.3.1
iOS Version - 17.7.1

Comment: Through what address are you trying to access the app when you are on your physical phone?

Comment: my ip address from Network Settings > WiFi

Comment: Any luck here? I'm facing same issue and I tried everything

Comment: @Niloufar Any change you got some progress about this?